# Property ' ' is used before its initialization

Tags: angular, rest, angular-material

I am following a youtube tutorial on how to consume a rest api in Angular Material table and am trying to apply it to my app. For some reason I get this error:

```
Property 'PERSONAL_DATA' is used before its initialization.
```

This is my ts.file, what do I have to do? Im very new to angular

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Personal } from 'src/app/models/personal.model';
import { PersonalService } from 'src/app/services/personal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personal-list',
  templateUrl: './personal-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personal-list.component.css']
})

export class PersonalListComponent implements OnInit {

  PERSONAL_DATA? : Personal[]
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'age'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Personal>(this.PERSONAL_DATA);

  constructor(private personalService: PersonalService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllPersonalTable();
  }

  private getAllPersonalTable(){
    let resp = this.personalService.getAllPersonal();
    resp.subscribe(report =>this.dataSource.data=report as Personal[])
  }
}
```

Comment: I would go with: `PERSONAL_DATA: Personal[] = []` initialized with empty array

Comment: @robert this for sure clears my error thank you!